# Kotlin обновление полей в activity

Tags: kotlin, android-spinner, listener

Нужно в текстовое поле вывести результат парсинга JSon'а от Google Directions
первая точка задана в массиве класса а вторая выбирается на картер через ответ от отPlacePicker. в onActivityResult я получаю выбранные мной координаты и в urlRead() я  собираю запрос, произвожу парсинг и на выходе получаю дистанцию в метрах

```
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?): /*LatLng?*/ {
   // var posLatLng: LatLng? = null
    if (requestCode === PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode === AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            val selectedPlace = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this)
            // Do something with the place
            val place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this)
            val stBuilder = StringBuilder()
            val sponelatlng=spinner.selectedItem as coalProvider
            posLatLng = place.latLng
            urlRead(LatLng(sponelatlng.Provider_latlng!!.latitude, sponelatlng.Provider_latlng!!.longitude),LatLng(place.latLng.latitude, place.latLng.longitude),"TravelMode")

        }
    }
    //return posLatLng
}
```

Немного о хранение координат заданных в массиве. их я получаю согласно выборному элементу в первом спиннере(первый спиннер это выборка кто продает(имя id LatLng координата и массив с товаром) а второй что продает(нахожу из вложенного в класс массива с параметрами имя и цена))

```
    fun initializeUI() {
    btnPickAddress.setOnClickListener { PlacePickerStart() }   //обработчик нажатия на кнопку вызова карты
    OneSpinnerContent()
    MassTextListener()
}

fun OneSpinnerContent() {
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<coalProvider>(applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Provider_array)
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
    spinner.adapter = adapter
    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
    {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>, view:View, position:Int, id:Long)
        {
            val con:coalProvider
            con = spinner.selectedItem as coalProvider

            con.Provider_coal[0].Coal_price
            OnPiceParceUpdate(con.Provider_coal[0].Coal_price)
            TwoSpinnerContent(con.Provider_coal)
           /* if (spinner.selectedItem != null) {
               // TwoSpinnerContent(con.Provider_coal)
            }*/
        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>) {}
    }

}

fun TwoSpinnerContent(tests: Array<coalProvider.Coal>) {
    val adapterSpTwo = ArrayAdapter<coalProvider.Coal>(applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tests)
    adapterSpTwo.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
    spinnerTwo.adapter = adapterSpTwo
    spinnerTwo.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
    {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>, view:View, position:Int, id:Long)
        {
            OnPiceParceUpdate((spinnerTwo.selectedItem as coalProvider.Coal).Coal_price)

        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>) {}
    }
}
```

Проблема вот в чем. Нужно проводить проверку и изменять поле(distanceCoal=findViewById(R.id.distanceCoal)) в зависимости от дистанции полученной через urlRead(). Но так как координаты я получаю и при смене позиции спиннера и при выборе новой точки на карте не получается вывести действительную дистанцию с учетом изменения координат используемых точек.
Как вариант я побывал вытащить из onActivityResult LatLng параметр чтоб с его помощью провести проверку в одном из слушателей спинера. Но оно выдает ошибку.
Может решение и банально но глаза замылились и я его не вижу

весь код:

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
companion object {
    private const val PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1
}

lateinit var spinner: Spinner
lateinit var spinnerTwo: Spinner
lateinit var onePiece: TextView
lateinit var coalMass: EditText
lateinit var allPrice: TextView
lateinit var tvPlaceDetails: TextView
lateinit var distancePrice: TextView
lateinit var distanceCoal: TextView


var Provider_array = arrayOfcoalProvider()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    bindView()
    initializeUI()
}

fun initializeUI() {
    btnPickAddress.setOnClickListener { PlacePickerStart() }   //обработчик нажатия на кнопку вызова карты
    OneSpinnerContent()
    MassTextListener()
}

fun OneSpinnerContent() {
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<coalProvider>(applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Provider_array)
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
    spinner.adapter = adapter
    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
    {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>, view:View, position:Int, id:Long)
        {
            val con:coalProvider
            con = spinner.selectedItem as coalProvider

            con.Provider_coal[0].Coal_price
            OnPiceParceUpdate(con.Provider_coal[0].Coal_price)
            TwoSpinnerContent(con.Provider_coal)
           /* if (spinner.selectedItem != null) {
               // TwoSpinnerContent(con.Provider_coal)
            }*/
        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>) {}
    }

}

fun TwoSpinnerContent(tests: Array<coalProvider.Coal>) {
    val adapterSpTwo = ArrayAdapter<coalProvider.Coal>(applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tests)
    adapterSpTwo.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
    spinnerTwo.adapter = adapterSpTwo
    spinnerTwo.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
    {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>, view:View, position:Int, id:Long)
        {
            OnPiceParceUpdate((spinnerTwo.selectedItem as coalProvider.Coal).Coal_price)

        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>) {}
    }
}

fun MassTextListener() {
    coalMass.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher
    {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, count:Int, after:Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int, before:Int, count:Int)
        {
            if (s.isNotBlank()) {
                when (s.toString().toInt()) {
                    0 -> coalMass.setText("0")
                    !in 1..40 -> coalMass.setText("40")
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

fun PlacePickerStart() {

    val builder = PlacePicker.IntentBuilder()
    val latLng = LatLng(53.77581, 91.49162)
    builder.setLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds.builder().include(latLng).build())
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?): LatLng? {
    var posLatLng: LatLng? = null
    if (requestCode === PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode === AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            val selectedPlace = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this)
            // Do something with the place
            val place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this)
            val stBuilder = StringBuilder()

            /* val placename = String.format("%s", place.name)
              val latitude = place.latLng.latitude.toString()
              val longitude = place.latLng.longitude.toString()
              val address = String.format("%s", place.address)
              stBuilder.append("Name: ")
              stBuilder.append(placename)
              stBuilder.append("\n")
              stBuilder.append("Latitude: ")
              stBuilder.append(latitude)
              stBuilder.append("\n")
              stBuilder.append("Logitude: ")
              stBuilder.append(longitude)
              stBuilder.append("\n")
              stBuilder.append("Address: ")
              stBuilder.append(address)
              tvPlaceDetails.setText(stBuilder.toString())*/

            val sponelatlng=spinner.selectedItem as coalProvider
            posLatLng = place.latLng
            urlRead(LatLng(sponelatlng.Provider_latlng!!.latitude, sponelatlng.Provider_latlng!!.longitude),LatLng(place.latLng.latitude, place.latLng.longitude),"TravelMode")

        }
    }
    return posLatLng
}

fun urlRead (start: LatLng, end: LatLng, mode: String) {
    val url = ("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=" + mode)
    url.httpGet().responseString { request, response, result ->
        when (result) {
            is Result.Failure -> {
            }
            is Result.Success -> {
                val res = result.value
                println(jsonParse(res))
            }
        }
    }
}

fun jsonParse(res: String):String{
    println("Result: $res")
    val parser: Parser = Parser()
    val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(res)
    val json: JsonObject = parser.parse(stringBuilder) as JsonObject
    var jojo = json.lookup<String?>("routes.legs.distance.value").value.toString()
    return jojo.replace("[","").replace("]","")
}

fun arrayOfcoalProvider(): Array<coalProvider> {
    val Provider_one = coalProvider("Разрез Аршановский", 0,LatLng(53.402971, 91.083748), Provider_coal = arrayOf(coalProvider.Coal("ДМСШ 0-25/1", 1500),coalProvider.Coal("ДО 25-50", 1700),coalProvider.Coal("ДПК 50-200", 1900),coalProvider.Coal("ДР 0-300 ", 1200)))
    val Provider_two = coalProvider("Разрез Белоярский",  1,  LatLng(53.529799,   91.410684),Provider_coal = arrayOf(coalProvider.Coal("ДМСШ 0-25/2", 1501),coalProvider.Coal("ДО 25-50", 1701),coalProvider.Coal("ДПК 50-200", 1901),coalProvider.Coal("ДР 0-300 ", 1201)))
    val Provider_Three = coalProvider(  "Разрез Черногорский", 2, LatLng(53.759367,   91.061604),Provider_coal = arrayOf(coalProvider.Coal("ДМСШ 0-25/3", 1502),coalProvider.Coal("ДО 25-50", 1702),coalProvider.Coal("ДПК 50-200", 1902),coalProvider.Coal("ДР 0-300 ", 1202)))
    val Provider_four = coalProvider(  "Разрез Восточнобейский", 3, LatLng(53.326586,   91.361016),Provider_coal = arrayOf(coalProvider.Coal("ДМСШ 0-25/4", 1503),coalProvider.Coal("ДО 25-50", 1703),coalProvider.Coal("ДПК 50-200", 1903),coalProvider.Coal("ДР 0-300 ", 1203)))
    val Provider_Five = coalProvider(  "Разрез Изыхский",   4,  LatLng(53.630114,   91.436063),Provider_coal = arrayOf(coalProvider.Coal("ДМСШ 0-25/5", 1504),coalProvider.Coal("ДО 25-50", 1704),coalProvider.Coal("ДПК 50-200", 1904),coalProvider.Coal("ДР 0-300 ", 1204)))
    return arrayOf(Provider_one,Provider_two,Provider_Three,Provider_four,Provider_Five)
}

fun bindView() {
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spPost)
    spinnerTwo = findViewById(R.id.spCoal)
    allPrice=findViewById(R.id.allPrice)
    coalMass = findViewById(R.id.coalMass)
    tvPlaceDetails = findViewById(R.id.placeDetails)
    distancePrice = findViewById(R.id.distancePrice)
    onePiece=findViewById(R.id.onePicePrace)
    distanceCoal=findViewById(R.id.distanceCoal)

}

fun resUpdate(){
    //Такой вызов функции как ниже можно устроить чтобв дальнейшем обращася resUpdate().OnPiceParceUpdate()
    /*fun OnPiceParceUpdate(PriceValue: Array<coalProvider.Coal>){
    }*/

    if(distanceCoal.text.isNotBlank()&& coalMass.text.isNotBlank()){
        val distance_price=(distanceCoal.text.toString().toInt()/1000)*15
        distancePrice.text=distance_price.toString()
    }

    if(coalMass.text.isNotBlank()&& distancePrice.text.isNotBlank()&& onePiece.text.isNotBlank()){
        val totalprice = coalMass.text.toString().toInt()*onePiece.text.toString().toInt()+ distancePrice.text.toString().toInt()
        allPrice.text = totalprice.toString()
    }
    if(coalMass.text.isNotBlank()){

    }

}

fun OnPiceParceUpdate(PriceValue: Int?){

    onePiece.text = PriceValue.toString()

}

}
```

Comment: В приведенном коде напрочь отсутствуют упоминания этой переменной

Comment: она в urlRead. я там отдельно ее выдергиваю из jsona и сразу присваиваю к полю

Comment: Зачем? Определите ее в `Activity` (ну или во фрагменте), а во всем местах, где происходит изменение координат точек - просто пересчитывайте

Comment: Не могу выдернуть возвращенные PlacePicke координаты из onActivityResult . поэтому и рассчитываю все в нем. И из за этого кода меняю координаты в спинере пока еще раз не перевыберу точку на PlacePicke в onActivityResult они не обновятся.

Comment: Что мешает методу `urlRead` сделать возвращаемым значением `LatLng` и класть его в свойство класса?

Comment: а это правильный вопрос... как бы то ниболо я решил приложить весь код( в urlRead  я затер присваивание к текстовому полю НО! оно когда то там было) сейчас попробую через urlRead передать

Comment: хм.. так разве функция urlRead если в ней сделать return LatLng не будет при попытке val Test = urlRead() присваивать переменной нечего?

Comment: и куда это вставить?

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо вызывать функцию запроса расстояния при каждом изменении координат точек и менять текст поля при получении результата

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    val distanceCoal : TextView by lazy { findViewById(R.id.distanceCoal) as TextView }

    fun TwoSpinnerContent(tests: Array<coalProvider.Coal>) {
        .....
        spinnerTwo.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
        {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>, view:View, position:Int, id:Long)
            {
                OnPiceParceUpdate((spinnerTwo.selectedItem as coalProvider.Coal).Coal_price)
                urlRead(.....)    <-------------
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>) {}
        }
    }
    // то же самое для OneSpinnerContent и метода выбора точки на карте

    fun urlRead (start: LatLng, end: LatLng, mode: String) {
        .....
        when (result) {
            is Result.Failure -> {}
            is Result.Success -> {
                distanceCoal.text = jsonParse(result)  <---------
            }
        }
        .....
    }
```

Comment: слушай. ты уже раньше помогал мне с кодом когда я спрашивал про обновление контента на двух спиннерах. Помнишь ты или нет не знаю. Но если да.Код хоть немного лучше стал?

Comment: @MrBazilevs да, стало лучше, но все еще есть куда расти :)